# Create pdf file using Aspose with good performance

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

I have web application & I am using Aspose to create pdf using Excel template file with around 15 columns. I am able to create pdf successfully but it is taking too much time for this. eg. for 28K records it is taking 2.5 to 3 min.

Using this approach -

```
WorkbookDesigner wd = new WorkbookDesigner();            
wd.Workbook = new Workbook(sbPath.ToString());
wd.SetDataSource(ds);
wd.Process();
wd.Workbook.Save(Page.Response, _reportFileName, ContentDisposition.Attachment, saveOpt);
```

Any inputs / steps to improve / increase performance ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no special steps to increase the performance. However, you can download and give a try to latest version (from aspose website) and see if it makes any difference in increasing the performance. Also you should use XLSX format instead of XLS format, because mostly performance is good in XLSX format and it is newer format. Also, are you getting the performance problems in pdf format or excel format? Are you setting OnePagePerSheet as true, because it will decrease the performance. You should set it false.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Thanks @shakeel. I am using latest version of Aspose & using xlsx format. Performance problem is when saving file in pdf format. For excel there isn't much now but in future we are expecting to create excel file for more than 28K records may be 100K or more. I looked in the all code used to generate excel & pdf. & found that this line - 'wd.Workbook.Save(Page.Response, _reportFileName, ContentDisposition.Attachment, saveOpt);' is using more time for pdf creation. Any help on this will be more than helpful.

Comment: Thanks, your code looks good. Could you please create a thread in Aspose.Cells forum with your complete sample code and source excel files which you are converting to pdf for our analysis. We will look into your issue and see where the problem is occurring and help you asap. Thanks for your cooperation.